# How to set number of tabs to display in action bar?

Tags: android

How can i cintroll number of tabs displayed in action bar?
To set tabs i use following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener {

    private List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        Tab tabVipusk = bar.newTab();
        tabVipusk.setText("Выпуск");
        tabVipusk.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tabVipusk);
        Tab tabConstuctor = bar.newTab();
        tabConstuctor.setText("Конструктор");
        tabConstuctor.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tabConstuctor);
        Tab tabPopular = bar.newTab();
        tabPopular.setText("Популярное");
        tabPopular.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tabPopular);
        Tab tabActual = bar.newTab();
        tabActual.setText("Актуальное");
        tabActual.setTabListener(this);

        bar.addTab(tabActual);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (fragList.size() > 0 && fragList.size() >= tab.getPosition()) {
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragList.get(tab.getPosition()));
        } else {
            fragList.add(new VipuskTabFragment());
            fragList.add(new ConstructorTabFragment());
            fragList.add(new PopularTabFragment());
            fragList.add(new ActualTabFragment());
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragList.get(tab.getPosition()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // if (fragList.size() >= tab.getPosition()) {
        // ft.remove(fragList.get(tab.getPosition()));
        // }

    }

}
```

But in portrait mode it shows only 3 tabs. But without margins, forth tab will abviously fit. So actually there is place for 4 tabs. How to display 4 tabs?

Comment: Note that using tabs in the action bar is deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview, and it should remain deprecated in future versions of Android. Please consider using some tab alternative, such as a `ViewPager` with `PagerTabStrip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used FragmentTabHost, whichi uses fixed tabs and perfectly fits for my cause